Monitor link click in Angular, where the HTML code is being sent from DB along with links
I have HTML code coming from database, it is being rendered with the help of innerHTML:
<li class="info-font" *ngFor="let item of element.instructionData" [innerHTML]="item"></li>

It may or may not contain links.
    "instructionData": [
        "Please make a Quick Request <a  target='blank' href='https://google.com'>here</a>",
        "Follow the steps mentioned the document"
    ]

I want to do some stuff with all the links which are clicked, those are within the HTML code coming from DB.


check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72260548/5909026

you can use angular's Renderer2 to bind event on your html.

You can use directive to monitor link clicks. It uses ElementRef to access the DOM element and Renderer2 to add event listeners in a safe manner.
you should declare the directive in the app.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MonitorLinkClickDirective } from './monitor-link-click.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MonitorLinkClickDirective],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [MonitorLinkClickDirective]
})
export class AppModule {}

app.directive.ts
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, AfterViewInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMonitorLinkClick]'
})
export class MonitorLinkClickDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.addLinkListeners();
  }

  addLinkListeners() {
    const links = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a');
    links.forEach((link: HTMLElement) => {
      this.renderer.listen(link, 'click', (event) => this.handleLinkClick(event, link));
    });
  }

  handleLinkClick(event: Event, link: HTMLElement) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Link clicked:', link.getAttribute('href'));
    // Perform any other action you need here
  }
}

app.component.html
<ul appMonitorLinkClick>
  <li class="info-font" *ngFor="let item of instructionData" [innerHTML]="item"></li>
</ul>

Please look into the below screenshot

